# Selection of method from overloads via its lambda argument's type definition doesn't work as expected

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have this bit of code at https://pl.kotl.in/Xo_dpVJjx

```
class Container<I>(
    val someValue: I,
)

// Method 1
fun <T, TNew> T.name(operation: (T) -> TNew): TNew {
    return operation(this)
}

// Method 2
fun <T, TNew> T.name(operation: (T) -> Container<TNew>): TNew {
    return operation(this).someValue
}

5.name { it.toString() }
```

which produces the following output:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Container<???> was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Container<TypeVariable(TNew)> was expected
```

My expectation here was that since the lambda returns a String, the compiler should've been able to choose the `Method 1` instead it chooses `Method 2`.

1. Is there a way for me to instruct the compiler to choose the former method for this situation?
2. Why does it choose `Method 2` over `Method 1`?

Answer (score 2):

The overload resolution algorithm selects the `(T) -> Container<TNew>` overload because of two reasons:

- Both `name` overloads are [*applicable*](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#determining-function-applicability-for-a-specific-call) to the call `5.name { it.toString() }`. This is because only the arity of the lambda argument is considered, but not the parameter/return types of the lambda. The types of lambdas can only be inferred after the overload to call is determined.

  > First, for every non-lambda argument of the function called, type inference is performed. Lambda arguments are excluded, as their type inference needs the results of overload resolution to finish.
- The `(T) -> Container<TNew>` overload is [*more specific*](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#choosing-the-most-specific-candidate-from-the-overload-candidate-set) than the `(T) -> TNew` overload. Everything that can be passed to a `(T) -> Container<TNew>` parameter, can be passed to a `(T) -> TNew` parameter, but not vice versa. Note that the two `TNew`s here are unrelated, different type parameters.

  This is similar to how `foo(String)` is a more specific overload than `foo(CharSequence)`. Everything you can pass to a `String` parameter can be passed to a `CharSequence` parameter, but not vice versa. Therefore, `foo(String)` is a more specific than `foo(CharSequence)`.

You can see another example of this situation in [this section of the spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#using-lambda-return-type-to-refine-function-applicability), where it is stated that lambda return types don't affect what the most specific overload is.

> ```
> @OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
> fun foo(cb: (Unit) -> String) = Unit // (1)
>
> @OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType
> fun foo(cb: (Unit) -> CharSequence) = Unit // (2)
>
> fun testError02() {
>     // Error: required String, found CharSequence
>     foo { a ->
>         val a: CharSequence = "42"
>         a
>     }
>     // Both (1) and (2) are applicable
>     // (1) is the only most specific candidate
>     //   We do not attempt refinement by the lambda return type
> }
> ```

So to fix your code, you either have to use different names for the two overloads, or don't pass a lambda, so that only one overload is applicable.

Examples:

```
5.name(Int::String) // OK
```

```
val f = { x: Int -> x.toString() }
5.name(f) // OK
```

Comment: Great explanation! I do know the fix for this; however, I don't like it. I keeps me from using the syntactical sugar and I have to add a new variable.

Comment: "The types of lambdas can only be inferred after the overload to call is determined." This seems more like an implementation deficiency. We should be able to determine the type definition of a lambda regardless of which overload it can be applied to.

Comment: @NSaran Yes, that is totally possible. Swift for example, can do this overload resolution and produce the intended result, but as a consequence, Swift also tends to take a lot longer to compile. I wouldn't call it a "deficiency" though. It's just a design choice that makes the implementation simpler. As you can see from the example in the spec, they are well aware of this. Anyway, if you want to discuss further about why they designed it this way, you can go on [LangDev.SE](https://langdev.stackexchange.com).